# Animating cover-sized background smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to make a background animation. Previously I used the following simple CSS solution:

```
#splash {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 2em solid #232323;
  border-bottom: 2em solid #232323;
  background-image: url("../img/splash.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0 100%;
  animation: moveSplash 15s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: moveSplash 15s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation: moveSplash 15s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  transition: opacity .5s;
  z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes moveSplash {
    from {
        background-position-y: 100%;
        background-position-x: 0%;
    }
    to {
        background-position-y: 0%;
        background-position-x: 100%;
    }
}
```

Which worked perfectly:

- whenever the screen was wider than taller, the background picture started to move from the bottom to the top, and it had the same width as the window's
- whenever the screen was taller than wider, the background picture started to move from the left to the right, and it had the same height as the window's

**HOWEVER,** there was one major problem with this method: the animation was very jumpy, that's why I started playing with `transition` and `transform: translate()`, but then I could not make the image perfectly fitting.

Is there any workaround out there to achieve a smooth background-image animation keeping it cover-sized?

**ANOTHER SOLUTION COULD BE** to set image's `width` and `height` to `100%`, and `object-fit` to `cover`. After this I would need to get the computed new dimensions of the image by Javascript or jQuery, however, I have tried `.width`, `.naturalWidth`, `.offsetWidth`, `.clientWidth`, and they returns 0. When I try this:

```
var oImg = document.getElementById('splash');

window.getComputedStyle(oImg).transformOrigin.split(' ')[0].replace('px', '')
window.getComputedStyle(oImg).transformOrigin.split(' ')[1].replace('px', '')
```

I get the window's dimensions (since the object's width and height are set to 100%), not the resized image's new size. If I could get the new size of the image, I could make a calculation where I find the max X and Y values.

Any idea how could I make this animation work smoothly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of performing the animation on the `background-image` itself, which is slow, I would suggest animating the entire element.

From what I can see you're trying to animate the background diagonally? Not horizontally and not vertically?

```
@keyframes moveSplash {
    from {
        transform: translateY(100%);
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    to {
       transform: translateY(0%);
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
}
```

If you can't make the image fit the div perfectly when using translate, then that is perhaps what your question really should've been about, because it's kind of "unconventional" to perform the transition on the `background-image` (because it's slow) and not the entire element (which makes better use of the available memory, and therefor, again – is faster).